# Css two boxes left and right with transform

Tags: css, html

As i titled i have two boxes like this [image] Guys now you can understand my problem ;) 
 in a responsive layout  i want to display this boxes with background yellow transform like this one of left is float left and other one is float right of the browser window. i think its too hard  please help me friend's :(

iam using css3

Comment: No, we can't understand your problem :(

Comment: No, we don't understand your problem.  What's the question?

Comment: are you using css3? are you using any kind of rendering engine? are you using printer paper and yellow crayons? are you open to suggestions on what to use to do this?

Comment: here i want to display this boxes with background yellow transform like this one of left is float left and other one is float right of the browser window...

Comment: how can i transform this div tags like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your (mostly) cross-browser solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
#oneOfYourRectangles
{
    -ms-transform:rotate(10deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(10deg); /* Opera */
}
#theOtherRectangle
{
    -ms-transform:rotate(350deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(350deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(350deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(350deg); /* Opera */
}
</style>
```

Ya know, I never did get around to testing to see if negative values are supported.

Also, note that obviously the 10deg and 350deg are just guesses. Replace them with whatever value fits best.

And, just for funsies, note that webkit (Safari and Chrome) support 3D transformations, too.